# Char type conversion incompatible

Tags: c++, constructor, char, type-conversion

A program based on constructors

```
    Error -Incompatible  Type conversion from char to char[100]
```

Code -

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class demo
    {
    public:
        char name[100];
//This is where char is declared
        int marks;

        demo()
        {
            marks = 0;
            name = "Pro"; 
//assigning value to the char
            cout<<"Working"<<endl;
        }

        void input()
        {
            cout<<"Enter Name and Marks"<<endl;
            cin>>name>>marks;
        }
        void output()
        {
            cout<<name<<"\t"<<marks<<endl;
        }
    };
```

i tried putting name in 'name' and "name" 
also i tried using type casting (char)
but it didnt seem to work

```
int main()
        {
            demo Obj1, Obj2;
    //creating objects
            Obj1.output();
            Obj2.input();
            Obj2.output();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string`? It would work flawlessly then.

Comment: we are not taught about it yet i will google it right away

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a `char` (a single character) and an array of `char` (which is a set of multiple characters) so are not logically assignable to each other.  The language doesn't allow assigning to arrays directly at all - it is necessary to copy elements one-by-one.

Comment: so i enter it as name = { "P","R"}; ?

Comment: Since you are using a raw array of `char`, rather than using `std::string`,  look up the function `strcpy()` in C++ header `<cstring>` or in C header (which C++ supports for backward compatibility, even if it is deprecated) `<string.h>`.

Comment: Your error message doesn't make sense. It should say "*from `const char*`*" or "*from `const char[4]`*", not "*from `char`*". Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator.

So this statement in the constructor

```
name = "Pro";
```

is wrong.

You have to write

```
#include <cstring>

//...

std::strcpy( name, "Pro" );
```

Or a simpler way is just to rewrite the constructor like

```
    demo() : name { "Pro" }, mark( 1 )
    {
        cout<<"Working"<<endl;
    }
```